# How to recover a error message from oData response [SAPUI5]

Tags: error-handling, sapui5, sap-fiori

I had this issue and i searched a lot how to fix it, but i can't find any solution at the moment...

well, the issue is the next error message, i can write the error but i need a specific entry of this batch.

[image: Error, Messagebox and Batch response.]

the code showed on the message box:

> {
> "message": "HTTP request failed",
> "headers": {
> "Content-Type": "application/xml;charset=utf-8",
> "Content-Length": "1333",
> "DataServiceVersion": "1.0"
> },
> "statusCode": "400",
> "statusText": "Bad Request",
> "responseText": "`<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><error xmlns=\"http://schemas .microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata\"><code>SY/530</code><message xml:lang=\"es\">No posee permisos para el Centro seleccionado</message><innererror><application><component_id/><service_namespace>/SAP/</service_namespace><service_id>ZQMGW_LECTURATANQUE_SRV</service_id><service_version>0001</service_version></application><transactionid>9488BBDEFA9E11E685950000705EE2FB</transactionid><timestamp>20170224144147.5230000</timestamp><Error_Resolution><SAP_Transaction>Run transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG on SAP Gateway hub system and search for entries with the timestamp above for more details</SAP_Transaction><SAP_Note>See SAP Note 1797736 for error analysis (https: //service. sap .com/sap/support/notes/1797736)</SAP_Note><Batch_SAP_Note>See SAP Note 1869434 for details about working with $batch (https: //service. sap. com/sap/support/notes/1869434)</Batch_SAP_Note></Error_Resolution><errordetails><errordetail><code/><message>No posee permisos para el Centro seleccionado</message><propertyref/><severity>error</severity><target/></errordetail><errordetail><code>/IWBEP/CX_SD_GEN_DPC_BUSINS</code><message>No posee permisos para el Centro seleccionado</message><propertyref/><severity>error</severity><target/></errordetail></errordetails></innererror></error>`"
> }

i need to recover the message tag only, but i don't know how....

the code what i'm using is the native error handling for Sapui5 Fiori Apps:

```
    constructor: function(oComponent) {
        this._oResourceBundle = oComponent.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
        this._oComponent = oComponent;
        this._oModel = oComponent.getModel();
        this._bMessageOpen = false;
        this._sErrorText = this._oResourceBundle.getText("errorText");

        this._oModel.attachMetadataFailed(function(oEvent) {
            var oParams = oEvent.getParameters();
            this._showServiceError(oParams.response);
        }, this);

        this._oModel.attachRequestFailed(function(oEvent) {
            var oParams = oEvent.getParameters("message");
            // An entity that was not found in the service is also throwing a 404 error in oData.
            // We already cover this case with a notFound target so we skip it here.
            // A request that cannot be sent to the server is a technical error that we have to handle though
            if (oParams.response.statusCode !== "404" || (oParams.response.statusCode === 404 && oParams.response.responseText.indexOf(
                    "Cannot POST") === 0)) {
                this._showServiceError(oParams.response);
            }
        }, this);
    },

    /**
     * Shows a {@link sap.m.MessageBox} when a service call has failed.
     * Only the first error message will be display.
     * @param {string} sDetails a technical error to be displayed on request
     * @private
     */
    _showServiceError: function(sDetails) {
        if (this._bMessageOpen) {
            return;
        }
        this._bMessageOpen = true;
        MessageBox.error(
            this._sErrorText, {
                id: "serviceErrorMessageBox",
                details: sDetails, 
                styleClass: this._oComponent.getContentDensityClass(),
                actions: [MessageBox.Action.CLOSE],
                onClose: function() {
                    this._bMessageOpen = false;
                }.bind(this)
            }
        );
    }
```

if someone knows how to recover that value, I'll be very greatful.

Greetings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i fixed this issue, changing this part of the code

```
if (oParams.response.statusCode !== "404" || (oParams.response.statusCode === 404 && oParams.response.responseText.indexOf(
                "Cannot POST") === 0)) {
            this._showServiceError(oParams.response);
        }
    }, this);
```

to

```
if (oParams.response.statusCode !== "404" || (oParams.response.statusCode === 404 && oParams.response.responseText.indexOf(
                    "Cannot POST") === 0)) {
                this._showServiceError($(oParams.response.responseText).find("message").first().text());

            }
        }, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have HCM_LRQ_CRE BSP application in your SAP ABAP Repository, actually it is an HCM Leave Request Fiori app. You can find there DataManager-dbg.js file. Look into **parseErrorMessages** method, it parses SAP messages nicely. Probably you can use it as a starting point.

Comment: i checked but isn't the app there, there is a way from recovery the text from the console? i can print a value, for example if i change the code

**this._sErrorText** to **this._sErrorText.responseText** 

i can print the entire response, but i need the message tag from that response.

Comment: The complete error message in bold characters is in JSON format: `{ "message": "HTTP request failed", …  seleccionadoerror" }`
If you copy & paste it into e.g. jsonlint.com, you can validate it and see the structure more clearly.

In your coding you already check for `oParams.response.statusCode   .`

What happens, if you do this. `_showServiceError(oParams.response.message);` ?
Is this, what you are looking for ?

Comment: I tried that thing before, and the only message what i have is the **"HTTP request failed"**  by the way, i fixed the issue with the code line posted the other day.... if you know a more elegant solution, can you help me?